# How to take incremental backup in tape drive

Tags: linux, shell-script, backup, centos, tape

I am having 1 tape drive and I want to take incremental backup of 5 folder to the tape drive on every Friday.

But the location of the five folders are on one server and the LTO mounted on a different machine.

How can I make the backups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure the user that you are going to use to make the backups:

1. can read all the 5 folders and their content
2. is able to use `ssh` into the server with the LTO ( lets call that 'remote') without authentication into an acount named `ltouser`. If necessary setup such an account.
3. can write to the tape after doing the `ssh`, assume the device name is `/dev/st0`

If all that is working you can use `tar` to make a backup.

```
tar -cv -f ltouser@remote:/dev/st0  YOUR_LOCAL_DIRECTORIES
```

Once that works, you can add the `--newer` option to start making incremental backups. To that option you can provide a date, but often it is more easy to use a file as reference:

```
cd parent/directory/of/your/stuff/to/backup
touch /var/tmp/next_dts_reference
tar -cv --new dts_reference -f ltouser@remote:/dev/st0  YOUR_LOCAL_DIRECTORIES
mv /var/tmp/next_dts_reference dts_reference
```

It is important to create the reference file before doing the backup, but move it afterwards. That way next week you don't miss files that were created *during* the backup.

Comment: thankyou Anthon..!!!!

when i am using this command

tar -cv -f ltouser@remote:/dev/st0  YOUR_LOCAL_DIRECTORIES

It show the following error:


tar: Cannot execute remote shell: No such file or directory
tar: ltouser@remote:/dev/nst0: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @user54478 you don't write if you have made sure the first 3 steps

Comment: ya i checked all the 3 steps...but still it is showing the error

Comment: I am not on CentOS, so your `tar` might work different. I am using gnu tar 1.26 (`tar --version`). Executed on the server, does 'tar cvf /dev/st0' write to the tape drive, and can you read that back without errors?

Comment: ok.i am using tar 1.23 and yes i can write to the tape and restore or read it also without error.
but when i copy data from one server to another is also showing me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 after Anthon's first 3 work:

Try

```
tar --rsh-command=/usr/bin/ssh -cv -f ltouser@remote:/dev/st0
```

Or whatever is your ssh path. Most system tar's compile in `/usr/bin/ssh` as `rsh-command` default. But sometimes the default is `/usr/bin/rsh` instead. And `rsh` might not exist.